# Easy, Fast, Secured Icon Recommendation

Tags: icon, resource-recommendations

I am trying to do a new website and there are 3 key points to it (Easy, fast, secured). I have already been thinking of using icons for those 3 words but I am not so sure yet. The site that I am doing is **for a car loan company** and I am open to any suggestions you guys might come up with. I still like the icons idea that I've had in mind and would love to know what icons would best represent those 3 words. I am open to any suggestions :)

**Here are my sketches/ideas:**

**For fast**, I was thinking of a car in motion so I made one (it's not perfect cause it's not done yet:

[image]

And **for easy**, I was thinking of a thumbs up icon. Maybe something like this:
[image]

And **for secured**, I was thinking of a lock. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Easy: a compact car. Fast: an Italian car. Secure: an armored truck. Or a Volvo ;)

Comment: For a car themed site, I'd go with a speedometer for fast.

Comment: Nobody's going to point out that "easy" is the facebook like button?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I'm not too big a fan of your secure and easy icons. Particularly the secure one - it made me think that the car is unlikely to get stolen, rather than that my family would be safe in it (which I gather is the point?).

I like @Yisela's suggestions...

Alternately, if you want a part of a car instead of the entire car, you could do something like:

**Easy:** the L that Learners use, or maybe just a basic steering wheel

**Fast:** a checkered racing flag, a cloud of smoke, a speedometer...

**Secure:** a carseat, a safety belt...

Answer (score 2):

Fast thought and even faster execution. Maybe something like this?

Personaly  for me only the "car" is correct. Of course it should be a bit faster ;) but I know that it's in progress yet. Thumb means rather OK than easy and the padlock means that something is locked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fast: should be a clock or timer like icon representing a time saving.

Secure you can choose a shield icon.

Answer (score 1):

Like the design. The car needs a bit more details but i know its a work in progress. What is the theme for the site ? The easy is kind of 2 way might mean good. But its a hard word to describe

Comment: It is for a car loan company.